# SQL Server Collation for non-European languages

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I want to use a non-European language collation on every column of a specific table. So:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn varchar(10)COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```

But `Ç` and `Ü` chars still stands in the cells.

I wish to change them into `C` and `U`

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Latin-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495%28VS.85%29.aspx) contains `Ç` (199) and `Ü` (220). Even if it didn't, it would still contain characters with value 199 and 220 - so you'd just see *different* tokens instead.

Frankly, if your data is now **or could ever be** non-ASCII, you'd do well to consider `nvarchar(...)` instead of `varchar(...)`